# Apply Jenks classification on a subset of features - PyQGIS3

Tags: symbology, pyqgis-3, classification, subset, jenks

I have a layer of watersheds, and a layer of diagnostic units, that are contained in each watersheds.

I have indicator values for each diagnostic unit. Indicator values have been normalised according to the units values inside each watershed. It means that for each watershed, I have indicator values between 0 and 1. (-99999 means no data, I will handle that later)

I would like to map indicator values according to Jenks classification, having thresholds different for each watershed. So apply Jenks classification only on a subset of features depending on watershed ID. I would like to automate the definition of rule based symbology at two levels, like in the picture below but with thresholds updated for each watershed.

[image]

The following code allows me to apply Jenks classification, but on the whole data set for now. **How can I apply the classification on each subset of indicator values ?**

According to the PyQGIS developper cookbook, there is maybe something to do with `QgsFeatureRequest()`, but instead of using an area of interest, using attribute values

[image]
[image]

```py
# layer with indicator values for each unit, and id of the watershed it belongs
niv1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('exempleNiveau1_UniteDiagnostic_CMH_valeur normalise')[0]
features = niv1.getFeatures()
bv_field = niv1.fields().indexFromName('NomBV_n1') #field with watershed id
ud_field = niv1.fields().indexFromName('ID_UD') #field with diagnostic units id
stab_field = niv1.fields().indexFromName('STAB_RIV_N') #indicator 1
rech_field = niv1.fields().indexFromName('RECH_NAP_N') #indicator 2
features = niv1.getFeatures()
bvUnique = niv1.uniqueValues(bv_field)
unique = list(bvUnique) # list of all unique watershed id
bv = []
ud = []
stab = []
rech = []

length = 0
for feat in features : #get values
    attr = feat.attributes()[bv_field]
    attr0 = feat.attributes()[ud_field]
    attr1 = feat.attributes()[stab_field]
    attr3 = feat.attributes()[rech_field]
    bv.append((str(attr)))
    ud.append((str(attr0)))
    stab.append((float(attr1)))
    rech.append((float(attr3)))
    length += 1
    
tab = []
valuesSet = []
for i in range(length): #save values in a list of list
    tab.append([str(bv[i]), str(ud[i]), stab[i], rech[i]])
tab.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
    
def classJenks(layer, set, targetField): # apply Jenks an all values
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    defaultColorRampNames = QgsStyle().defaultStyle().colorRampNames()
    mode = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Jenks
    colorRamp = QgsStyle().defaultStyle().colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[25])  #Spectral name
    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.createRenderer(layer, targetField, 5, mode, symbol, colorRamp )

    layer.setRenderer(renderer)

createSubset(niv1, unique[0], 3) # example for 1st watershed and indicator 2 (by index in tab)
classJenks(niv1, valuesSet, 'RECH_NAP_N') # example for 1st watershed and indicator 2 (by index in tab)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried

```py
a=0
exp = QgsExpression('NomBV_n1 ILIKE \'%Bécancour%\'')
request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
for feat in niv1.getFeatures(request):
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(niv1.geometryType())
    defaultColorRampNames = QgsStyle().defaultStyle().colorRampNames()
    mode = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.Jenks
    colorRamp = QgsStyle().defaultStyle().colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[22])  #Spectral name
    renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.createRenderer(niv1, 'RECH_NAP_N', 5, mode, symbol, colorRamp )
    a += 1
    
    niv1.setRenderer(renderer)
```

the value of 'a' allows me to check if the name of the watershed is recognized, and it's ok. The colorRamp is created, but I obtain a symbology for all the diagnsotic units...

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
Thanks to the following code, I can get the thresholds for the 1st watershed, then I will reclassify index values with classes going from 1 to 5 (I don't need to keep raw values), comparing indicator values with Jenks classes limits. It will then be easier to apply the symbology.

```py
# Get Jenks classes from a subset to be able to use them
exp = QgsExpression('NomBV_n1 ILIKE \'%Bécancour%\'')
request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
classesAsADict = [
    {"label": j.label(), "lowerBound": j.lowerBound(), "upperBound": j.upperBound()}
    for j in QgsClassificationJenks().classes(
        [i["RECH_NAP_N"] for i in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures(request)], 5
    )
]
```

I finally got help to do all the process with R studio so I will not post the full solution with PyQGIS

Comment: Could be wrong as I'm not sure I understood well but you need to use `your_layer.setSubsetString("ADMIN ILIKE '%Bécancour%'")` It does the same action as using right click on a layer in the layer tree panel, choosing "Filter..." and executing the expression to filter your layer. Then, you can simply use the Jenks related functions on the layer now filtered. To remove filter on your layer, do `your_layer.setSubsetString("")` You may look at https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-filtering-features/ as it could be more clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
your_layer.setSubsetString("ADMIN ILIKE '%Bécancour%'")
```

It does the same action as using right click on a layer in the layer tree panel, choosing "Filter..." and executing the expression to filter your layer. Then, you can simply use the Jenks related functions on the layer now filtered.

To remove filter on your layer, do

```py
your_layer.setSubsetString("")
```

You may look at https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-filtering-features/ as it could be more clearer.

**Edit:**

As it seems you want to make like a jenks by watershed (something like a "subjenk"), you may start from below logic:

```
# Get Jenks classes from a subset to be able to use them

classesAsADict = [
    {"label": j.label(), "lowerBound": j.lowerBound(), "upperBound": j.upperBound()}
    for j in QgsClassificationJenks().classes(
        [i["your_field"] for i in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures(request)], 5
    )
]
```

Then, you will create a rule based renderer and add for each of your watershed your Jenks rules combining where id of watershed matches and where values between your Jenks upper and lower bound for the particular watershed.

Comment: Sorry I went too fast, your solution allows to diplay watershed classification one by one, but I would like to display the classification for all the watersheds, with one classification adapted to each one : for the same layer, having 5 symbols for each watershed, each one corresponding to a class defined according to Jenks' Natural Breaks.

Comment: Thanks ThomasG77, your scripts works great to get the thresholds !